# R: split and duplicate a row

Tags: r, strsplit

My data frame has a columns that I'd like to split by dashes, duplicate rows with characters to the left and right of dashes. I know how to split and duplicate, but cannot figure out how to keep parts of strings. Pretty terrible description - I think it's just easier to show the data frame and desired output.

```
tmp = structure(list(Unit.Types = c("10 - 12 Pack 11.2 - 14.9 oz Bottle or Can", 
"8 - 12 Pack 11.5 - 16 oz Bottle or Can"), Row.Count = c("899", 
"305"), Test = c("B", "A")), .Names = c("Unit.Types", "Row.Count", 
"Test"), row.names = c(104L, 196L), class = "data.frame") 

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

tmp2 = tmp %>% mutate(Unit.Types = strsplit(as.character(Unit.Types), "-")) %>% unnest(Unit.Types)
tmp2

  Row.Count Test             Unit.Types
1       899    B                    10 
2       899    B          12 Pack 11.2 
3       899    B  14.9 oz Bottle or Can
4       305    A                     8 
5       305    A          12 Pack 11.5 
6       305    A    16 oz Bottle or Can
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
                                 Unit.Types Row.Count Test
1 10 Pack 11.2 oz Bottle or Can       899    B
2 10 Pack 14.9 oz Bottle or Can       899    B
3 12 Pack 11.2 oz Bottle or Can       899    B
4 12 Pack 14.9 oz Bottle or Can       899    B
5 8 Pack 11.5 oz Bottle or Can       305    A
6 8 Pack 16 oz Bottle or Can       305    A
7 12 Pack 11.5 oz Bottle or Can       305    A
8 12 Pack 16 oz Bottle or Can       305    A
```

Or at least like that, split by dash with "oz"

```
                                 Unit.Types Row.Count Test
1 10 - 12 Pack 11.2 oz Bottle or Can       899    B
2 10 - 12 Pack 14.9 oz Bottle or Can       899    B
3 8 - 12 Pack 11.5 oz Bottle or Can       305    A
4 8 - 12 Pack 16 oz Bottle or Can       305    A
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are all rows of the form "10 - 12 Pack 11.2 - 14.9 oz Bottle or Can"?

Comment: Can also be "10 Pack 14 - 16 oz Can"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this function

```
f <- function(x){
    strsplit(x, " Pack | oz Bottle or Can")[[1]] %>%
    strsplit(" - ") %>%
    expand.grid() %>%
    mutate(V = paste(Var1, "Pack", Var2, "oz Bottle or Can")) %>%
    `[[`("V")
}
```

It is to be applied to strings that are in the `Unit.Types` column. Example:

```
> f(tmp$Unit.Types[[1]])
[1] "10 Pack 11.2 oz Bottle or Can" "12 Pack 11.2 oz Bottle or Can"
[3] "10 Pack 14.9 oz Bottle or Can" "12 Pack 14.9 oz Bottle or Can"
```

Then with this function we can do the following:

```
ans <- tmp %>% split(1:nrow(tmp)) %>%
lapply(function(x) data.frame(Unit.Types = f(x$Unit.Types),
                              Row.Count = x$Row.Count,
                              Test = x$Test
                              )
       ) %>%
do.call(rbind, .)
row.names(ans) <- NULL
```

`ans` is our desired data.frame.

**UPD** Concerning your comment: we can use regex which matches pairs of numbers separated by `' - '`, or just numbers and rewrite `f` with it.

```
regex <- "[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?( - [0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?)?"

f <- function(x){
    m <- gregexpr(regex, x)
    matches <- regmatches(x, m)[[1]]
    nonmatches <- regmatches(x, m, invert = T)[[1]][-1]
    strsplit(matches, " - ") %>%
    expand.grid(stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
    apply(MARGIN = 1, function(y) rbind(y, nonmatches) %>%
                                  c %>%
                                  paste(collapse = ""))
}
```

This function can handle even strings with three or more number specifications:

```
> x <- "2 - 3 big packs of 10 - 12 Pack 11.2 - 14.9 oz Can"
> f(x)
[1] "2 big packs of 10 Pack 11.2 oz Can" "3 big packs of 10 Pack 11.2 oz Can"
[3] "2 big packs of 12 Pack 11.2 oz Can" "3 big packs of 12 Pack 11.2 oz Can"
[5] "2 big packs of 10 Pack 14.9 oz Can" "3 big packs of 10 Pack 14.9 oz Can"
[7] "2 big packs of 12 Pack 14.9 oz Can" "3 big packs of 12 Pack 14.9 oz Can"
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great with "oz Bottle or Can" end of string. In more general cases the ending is repeated twice (e.g. end of string can be "blah.. 10 - 12 oz Can" or other form - bottle, keg, etc).